# React and Material-UI: Label of TextField overlapping with date format (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, textfield, date-formatting

I am a beginner in React development and I apologize in advance for asking what might be a basic question. I am currently working on a React project that utilizes Material-UI for styling and UI components. In my form, I have a TextField component where users can input a date. However, I am encountering an issue where the label of the TextField overlaps with the desired date format (dd-mm-yyyy).

Here is my code for the TextField component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Paper, IconButton, Typography, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Search as SearchIcon, SwapHoriz as SwapIcon } from '@material-ui/icons';
import '../styles/Home.css';


return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
            <TextField  label="Depart" type="date" fullWidth className='InputBase'      variant='filled'/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
            <TextField label="Return" type="date" fullWidth className='InputBase' variant='filled'/>
          </Grid>`

      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  </div>
```

I tried changing the height but it doesn't look good. The label and the input field seem to occupy the same space, resulting in the overlapping. Is there any other way of doing it

I kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue. I am eager to learn and would greatly appreciate any suggestions, alternative approaches, or insights you can provide. Thank you so much for your help!

[The label and Date Format Overlaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzya.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

```
<TextField
  label="Date"
  placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
  InputLabelProps={{
    style: { top: '-0.6rem' },
  }}
  // Rest of the TextField props
/>
```